# Bookmark :~:text= specifications

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, microsoft-edge

A web url of the form `someUrl#:~:text=abc%20def` will highlight in yellow the words `abc def` on the page, at least in Chrome. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/#:~:text=Top%20Questions but not https://stackoverflow.com/#:~:text=Top%20Quest

Where can I find documentation on this? This does not seem to work in Edge.

When is the highlight applied in the page's life cycle? I find that sometimes text rendered much later by Ajax calls are highlighted?

Comment: I'm in favor of Hari's answer and you can find more information about this feature [in this page](https://github.com/WICG/ScrollToTextFragment). The feature is also available on the new Edge Chromium now. I think the highlight is applied on load, as it says in the article: *When the page is loaded, the browser highlights the text and scrolls it into view.*

Comment: Your link is more specific. Hari's link wasn't specifying `text=`. It was just mentioned in passing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a feature of chrome. see https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4733392803332096

Also, everything appearing in the urlpath after the #.("search") does not travel to the server, and it can only be parsed by either the browser (for special values, such as the one you discovered, or for anchors or id'ed elements), or by in-page script (e.g. you can choose to display different content for different search values).

Comment: It works with Safari as well